# Returning an array from a higher order function

Tags: javascript, arrays, return, higher-order-functions

```
function map(arr, fn){
for(var i = 0; i <arr.length; i++){
    fn(arr[i]);
    //some code here
    }
}

map([1,2,3,4], function(val){
    return console.log(val * 2);
});
```

I am having trouble trying to get the result into an array form. For example, [2,4,6,8].  I feel like I know how to do it but I'm blanking out.

Comment: Your need to return an array from your `map` function. Also, `console.log()` wouldn't return what you're passing to it but rather `undefined`.

Comment: @haim770 I used console.log() to see the output. Did you try the code? It prints out the result. I'm not sure what you're talking about...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback (`fn`) should mutate the array value at hand and `map` should return the array. See the snippet. Furthermore: just use the native `Array.map` method I'd say ([see mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for that)

```js
function map(arr, fn){
  for(var i = 0; i <arr.length; i++){
    arr[i] = fn(arr[i]);
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(
  map([1,2,3,4], function(val){  return val*2; })
);

// but hey, who needs it
console.log([1,2,3,4].map(v => v*2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your callback needs to return a new value for each item in array and you need to create a new array of those values

```js
function map(arr, fn){
   return arr.map(fn);
}

var res = map([1,2,3,4], function(val){
    return val * 2;
});

console.log(res)
```